# How to display a list with "ireport"?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have this:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

ArrayList<String> prueba= new ArrayList<String>();
 prueba.add("juan");
 prueba.add("pablo");
 prueba.add("pedro");

parameters.put("NombresDeMuestra", prueba);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

I need show this:

```
juan

pablo

pedro
```

My jrxml is this:

```
    <parameter name = "NombresDeMuestra" class = "java.util.List"/>

<title>
    <band height="79">
 <textField>
            <reportElement x="257" y="11" width="100" height="19"/>
            <textFieldExpression>
                <![CDATA[$P{NombresDeMuestra}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
```

But this show: [juan,pablo,pedro]. Thanks

Comment: The "normal" way is to hand out the list `prueba` as data in the `fillReport()` method. You gives an empty datasource. A parameter is a parameter, normally a scalar value for your report (e.g. the user name). To print the parameter `NombresDePrueba` in that way is an requirement or did you get something wrong with JasperReport ?

Comment: I do not understand,I can not use array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get what you want, you may do like this:

```
String s = "";
for(String z : prueba) s = s + z + "\n\n";
parameters.put("NombresDeMuestra", s);
```

and

```
<parameter name = "NombresDeMuestra" class = "java.lang.String"/>
```